# How to configure JMeter to hit a specific queue on my local ActiveMQ server?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmeter

I have a specific XML-based messaged format:

```
<myMessage>
    <!-- A whole bunch of stuff -->
</myMessage>
```

How do I configure JMeter:

[image]

...to send, say, 10K `<myMessage>`s to an `all-messages` queue on an ActiveMQ server running locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html

You have different options for message sources:

- Use Random file from files located in a folder
- Use textarea to put message, this message will contain some variable loaded from CSV

Note:

- Proxy feature only exists from HTTP protocole
- Your screenhot is strange, I don't have these option in JMeter. Furthermore, you should upgrade to last versions (2.7 or 2.8) of JMeter as it contains many fixes regarding JMS.

Answer (score -1):

There should be an option to "record" traffic being as an proxy in JMeter. After setting up your proxy (which will redirect your traffic to your server and record your XML payloads),  you can replay your macros with the changes you desire and can even read from files for different inputs... good luck.